# Using microphone to calibrate headphone sound

Tags: audio, headphones, equalizer

I have this second brand headphones that sound too "bassy" and did not come with a calibration tag. Manufacturer website doesn't offer much help. 
I thought it may be fixed with the help of an system wide equalizer to accurately lower the bass frequencies. Maybe playing sound and pointing microphone to headphones, it would retrieve enough noise to achieve this. I'm looking for recommendations on how to do it and what software to use. Maybe recording microphone input and check the frequencies in Audacity ?

Answer (score 1):

That is not how to go about it, unless you're looking to gain qualifications as  pro sound engineer [not required for this simple task ;)

Just do it by ear.
Those are the things currently telling you it's 'wrong', use them to tell you when it's 'right.

Google for some freeware audio EQ plugin like [Audio APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/), play some music &/or an audiobook & twiddle til it sounds right.
Done.

Trying to record from a mic with no known EQ characteristics back to a set of headphones with equally unknown but suspect characteristics will have you pulling your hair out, & that's if you manage to do it without feeding one straight back round to the other & squealing at you.